# UCB proof is using an assumption that is never justified.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

I'm walking though deep mind's course on reinforcement learning:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQJP3Z2Ho8U&t=4940s

at timestamp 1:14:40, the lecturer states that we assume that we have a time step "m", <= t (the current time step), for which:

$N_m(a)\Delta_a \leq x_alog(m)$

where:

1. $N_m(a)$ is the number of times we picked action a.
2. $\Delta_a$ is the expected regret for picking action a.
3. $x_a$ is some constant we did not determine yet.

the rest of the proof seem to rely on this assumption.
but, the lecturer never stops to justify it!
what if you don't have this kind of a time step? the whole proof becomes useless, isn't it?

Comment: Obviously it’s hugely dependent on context and more specific details, but at any step $a$, you can find a value of $x_a$ such that the inequality is true.

Comment: My experience with youtube math videos is bad , however I did not see this video. Therefore , I cannot judge whether it belongs to the (very rare) cases where it is not just clickbait with little mathematical content and debatable potential for entertainment. Considering this experience , I tend to assume that you are right.